# Inserting multiple JPGs into different cells with one button via VBA userforms

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am working on an unserform, which allows the user to insert pictures into specific cells as attachments. So far, one button is responsible for one picture for one specific cell. I was wondering if it was possible to click one button multiple times, inserting multiple pictures into multiple cells, changing the position of the next picture depending on the number of pictures already inserted.

This is the code I am using for one button to insert one picture into a single specific cell of a worksheet:

```
 Private Sub CommandButtonUpload_Click()

Dim PicLoad As Variant
PicLoad = Application.GetSaveAsFilename

Dim PicPath As String, Pic As Picture, ImageCell As Range

    PicPath = PicLoad
    Set ImageCell = Worksheets("Example").Range("a62")

    Set Pic = Worksheets("Example").Pictures.Insert(PicPath)
    With Pic
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Left = ImageCell.Left
        .Top = ImageCell.Top

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It is possible. • But your description of the problem is a way to broad to give a more precise answer. *"into different cells"* is not precise enough. Is the first cell always `A62` and the other *"different"* cells are below? Please give a more precise description and a screenshot might help too. • The idea would be to use a static counter and using `Range.Offset` to move from the original cell by the amount of the counter.

Comment: Hey. Yes- The first Cell is always A62. The next pictures are supposed to be below that, so for example A92, A122, ... with a constant intervall of 30 cells below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a static variable `PicCount` to keep track of the amount of pictures already added.

```
Private Sub CommandButtonUpload_Click()
    Dim PicLoad As Variant
    PicLoad = Application.GetSaveAsFilename
    
    If PicLoad = False Then Exit Sub 'user pressed cancel so exit

    Dim PicPath As String
    PicPath = PicLoad

    Static PicCount As Long

    Dim ImageCell As Range
    Set ImageCell = Worksheets("Example").Range("A" & cStr(62 + PicCount * 30))
    PicCount = PicCount + 1

    Dim Pic As Picture
    Set Pic = Worksheets("Example").Pictures.Insert(PicPath)
    With Pic
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Left = ImageCell.Left
        .Top = ImageCell.Top
    End With
End Sub
```